# Equivalent of RecordSet.MoveNext while Not EOF in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6, eof

I'm using a `DataReader` to display informations stored in a table.

I created Two button to go to `next` record and to `go back`.

In VB6 I used this code :

```
While Not Recordset1.EOF
Recordset1.MoveNext
End While
```

In `ASP.NET` I didn't find a way to do like it, because DataReader hasn't the EOF property.

**EDIT :**

```
While Not Recordset1.BOF
Recordset1.MovePrevious
End While
```

How can I convert this last code (VB6) to ASP.NET ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `Read` instead of `MoveNext` and it'll return false if there aren't any more records.
So:

```
While rdr.Read()
    .... ' process this row
End While
```

Comment: The problem is that I must close the DataReader after every MyReader.Read(). 

So i don't remember the last record where I was.

Comment: Also how can I go back without having any debug.

Comment: @AZIRAR: Sorry, I didn't understand your exact question. I think you shouldn't be using a DataReader at all if you have a back button, DataReaders are forward only. I'd suggest that instead you use the DataReader to quickly load up a DataTable in memory and then you can read the previous or next record from that table easily enough. Here's an article about loading up the table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx You could then even do `Dim rows() as DataRow = table.Select()` and end up with normal array etc.

Answer (score 0):

Azirar, ho1 is correct in that you should use a DataTable.  If you're updating after every post back and only need a single record you could still use a DataReader, but set up your SQL statement to get a single row (storing the appropriate information needed in your SQL statement (or better yet stored procedure) to get that single record back within query strings or session variables).